# creating csp trusted type policy in angular universal application

Tags: node.js, angular, security, content-security-policy, angular-universal

I wanted to know, how to create a trusted type default policy on the server. I have tried installing trusted-types npm package and create the policy like this

```
const tt=require('trusted-types');

tt.TrustedTypePolicyFactory.createPolicy('default', {
createHTML: (code)=>code,
createScriptURL: (url) => url,
createScript: (code)->code
});
```

But I'm getting this error

[image: error description]